# Set flexbox order property

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to change the `order` of a search-form I have on my header. On the desktop it is as it's supposed to be.

For now on the mobile I am just using `display:none` on the mobile, but I would like it be at the top of my head markup instead, in this case before the logo and menu icon and span 100% width.

I would like to do this with `order: -1;` on the default mobile code, and then on the desktop media query set the order for the search-form to `order: 1;`.

I have setup a [pen](http://codepen.io/lupis/pen/JYZVVE) for this.

Something similar to this is what I would like.

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="logo fa fa-diamond">
    <h1>My</h1>
    <h2>party</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="search-form">
    <form>
      <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Sök..." required>
      <input class="button" type="button" value="Sök..">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.search-form {
   display: flex;
   order: -1;
 }
```

CSS (desktop):

```
@media all and (min-width: 630px) {
  .search-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
    order:99;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```css
header, .search-form {
  flex-direction: column;
}
form {
  display: flex;
}
.search {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
@media all and (min-width: 630px) {
  header, .search-form {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: url(https://images.rapgenius.com/cd9kack9vtcvcz8yr7h9kliji.1000x625x1.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #999;
  background-image
}
.fa-gift,
.fa-glass,
.fa-calendar,
.fa-facebook,
.fa-cutlery {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.8em;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #FF00FF;
}
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fa-diamond {
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 10px;
}
.fa-times,
.fa-bars {
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
/* Däljer checkboxen fär menyn*/

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
/* Döljer Font icon Krysset i default läge */

#nav-toggle,
.fa-times {
  display: none;
}
/* Visar menu för  mobil i när checkboxen är checked läge */

#nav-toggle:checked + #wrapper nav {
  display: block;
}
/* Döljer font icon Bar när checkboxen är checked läge */

#nav-toggle:checked + #wrapper header .fa-bars {
  display: none;
}
/* Visar font icon krysset när checkboxen är i checked läge */

#nav-toggle:checked + #wrapper header .fa-times {
  display: block;
}
/* Döljer menyn för mobil i default läge */

nav {
  display: none;
}
/*För mobilen så sätter vi menyn på display:flex och flex-flow:column wrap för att visa menyn i en kolumn*/

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5DDAF4;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
nav ul a {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  color: #92b4f2;
}
.search-form {
  display: flex;
  order: -1;
}
@media all and (min-width: 630px) {
  /* Döljer meny trigger för desktop */
  header > label {
    display: none;
  }
  /* visar menyn för desktop */
  nav {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .fa-gift,
  .fa-glass,
  .fa-calendar,
  .fa-facebook,
  .fa-cutlery {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  h1,
  h2 {
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
  .search-form {
    display: block;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
    order: 99;
  }
  .search {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.7);
    border: 0px solid #dbdbdb;
    color: white;
  }
  .button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    left: -8px;
    border: 2px solid #207cca;
    background-color: #207cca;
    color: #fafafa;
  }
}
header,
.search-form {
  flex-direction: column;
}
form {
  display: flex;
}
.search {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
@media all and (min-width: 630px) {
  header,
  .search-form {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Vi använder oss av en checkbox för att visa och dölja menyn på mobilen utan javascript-->
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="logo fa fa-diamond">
      <h1>My</h1>
      <h2>party</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="search-form">
      <form>
        <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Sök..." required>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Sök..">
      </form>
    </div>
    <label for="nav-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-gift"></i> Presenter</li>
      <li><i class=" fa fa-glass"></i> Party</li>
      <li><i class=" fa fa-calendar"></i> Events</li>
      <li><i class=" fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</li>
      <li><i class=" fa fa-cutlery"></i>Middagar</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the header is in 'document  order', just as you would want for mobile use. Your construction needs a wrapper and a @media query that changes the order of elements for larger devices:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 header {
  /* a column of two rows: logo+search (need a wrapper) and label */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  order: 1;
  /* row 1 of header */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
label {
  order: 2
}
/* row 2 of header */

.search-form {
  /* first in .wrapper  */
}
.logo {
  /* second in .wrapper */
}
form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
@media all and (min-width: 630px) {
  .logo {
    order: 1
  }
  .search-form {
    order: 2;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
/* {
  outline: 1px dashed red
}
/* just for debugging */
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search-form">
      <form>
        <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Sök..." required>
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Sök..">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="logo fa fa-diamond">
      <h1>My</h1>
      <h2>party</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="nav-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </label>
</header>
```